# Inserting Date gives error ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Tags: sql, oracle

Insert date into WSH_Delivery_Details_Interface (https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/r13_update17c/scmcs_gs/OEDSC/WSH_DELIVERY_DETAILS_tbl.htm) throws this error

Query :

```
insert into WSH_DEL_DETAILS_Interface
    (DELIVERY_DETAIL_INTERFACE_ID, CREATION_DATE, Date_Requested)
values
    (30010985553,
     TO_DATE('11/12/2018T05:10:30-00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY '),
     TO_DATE('11/12/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY'));
```

**Sample Record in creation_date and date_requested column:**

```
Date_Requested    Creation_Date
16-JUN-10         17-JUN-10 03.40.31.865000000 PM
```

Comment: Which column is the problem one?

Comment: creation_date and date_requested

Comment: Now you can remove the other columns from the insert, to make the question easier to read.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: @AlexPoole Already existing record creation_Date has timestamp ..  So i guess it's needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error can be reduced to:

```
select TO_DATE('11/12/2018T05:10:30-00:00','DD/MM/YYYY ') from dual;

Error report -
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

Which is reasonable as it clearly doesn't match. You need to include the time elements in your format mask, and also a character literal for the fixed 'T', and for the fixed time zone offset:

```
select TO_DATE('11/12/2018T05:10:30-00:00','DD/MM/YYYY"T"HH24:MI:SS"-00:00"') from dual;

TO_DATE('11/12/2018
-------------------
2018-12-11 05:10:30
```

If that 'time zone' part isn't fixed and needs to be honoured, then you can use `to_timestamp_tz()` instead of `to_date()`:

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('11/12/2018T05:10:30-00:00','DD/MM/YYYY"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM')
from dual;

TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('11/12/20
-------------------------
2018-12-11 05:10:30.0 GMT
```

I've included `.FF` in the format model as well as the time zone offset elements (you could use `TZR` instead of `TZH:TZM` if you might be passed regions instead of offsets), since your example of existing data has fractional seconds, even though your literal string does not in this case

And you can `cast()` that to a date or plain timestamp if necessary, or possibly normalise to UTC if the input values can be other zones/offsets:

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('11/12/2018T04:10:30-01:00','DD/MM/YYYY"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM') as orig,
  SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(
    TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('11/12/2018T04:10:30-01:00','DD/MM/YYYY"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM')) as utc
from dual;

ORIG                         UTC                  
---------------------------- ---------------------
2018-12-11 04:10:30.0 -01:00 2018-12-11 05:10:30.0
```

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole